# Multivariate functions with both additive and multiplicative separation of variables

Tags: functions

If $f(x)+g(y)=h(x)k(y)$ as functions of $x$, $y$, what kind of restrictions does this impose on the functions $f$, $g$, $h$, $k$?

Comment: Not much really. You've hit on a large number of degrees of freedom here. If k and g are both constants, then h is just f + constant, etc. And this is even with the added restriction of continuous and differentiable, which is not in the original statement of the problem

Comment: @NinadMunshi You are right. Still, I need, if possible, a description of the whole class of such functions.

Comment: Is it okay to restrict our attention to locally $C^2$ functions at least? Why do you need a description for these functions? That can help point us to what restrictions are reasonable. Because without even continuity, then this could be some pathological thing like the rational indicator function.

Comment: Also, what is the domain of these functions?

Comment: If you are asking about differentiable functions of a real variable, try differentiating with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$.  When I do this, I get $h'(x)k'(y)=0$ for all $x$ and $y$, which restricts things a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose neither $h$ nor $k$ is a constant function, that is, that there exist $x_i$ and $y_i$ such that $h(x_1)\ne h(x_2)$ and $k(y_1)\ne k(y_2)$.  Then, since $f(x)+g(y)=h(x)k(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, we have, by substituting $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$ and subtracting, $$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=(h(x_1)-h(x_2))k(y)$$ for all $y$,  and hence (by similarly substituting $y=y_1$ and $y=y_2$ and subtracting)  $$0=(h(x_1)-h(x_2))(k(y_1)-k(y_2)).$$ But the right hand side of this equation is the product of two non zero quantities.

Thus either the codomain of these functions (which I suppose is a ring, or the problem statement does not make sense) has zero divisors, or at least one of $h$ and $k$ must be a constant function.